# Java application that takes input from the user and returns the regarding information from Excel File

Tags: java, excel, user-interface, input, apache-poi

I am writing a Java app with simple GUI that takes 5 inputs from user; brand, type, delivery, package, and name. I also have an Excel file like this: There are several numbers of brands listed like 1,2,3..
Types, delivery types etc. I want to return the code of the product that user have written. The code should be like this: if the given brand is the second brand (2), type is the 5, delivery 11, and the product is the 3th element of the 8th group, the code is : 251183. Which path should i follow? Thank you for the answers.

I am using Apache poi but I do not know how to pick the columns or rows and append them to code from excel.
Here is my code:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

public class ProductCodeGenerator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JLabel brandLabel, typeLabel, deliveryLabel, packageLabel, nameLabel, codeLabel;
    private JTextField brandField, typeField, deliveryField, packageField, nameField;
    private JButton generateButton;

    public ProductCodeGenerator() {
        // Create the GUI components
        brandLabel = new JLabel("Marka:");
        typeLabel = new JLabel("Tip:");
        deliveryLabel = new JLabel("Gönderim Tipi:");
        packageLabel = new JLabel("Paket:");
        nameLabel = new JLabel("İsim:");
        codeLabel = new JLabel("Ürün Kodu:");
        brandField = new JTextField(10);
        typeField = new JTextField(10);
        deliveryField = new JTextField(10);
        packageField = new JTextField(10);
        nameField = new JTextField(10);
        generateButton = new JButton("OK");
        generateButton.addActionListener(this);

        // Add the components to the GUI
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6, 2));
        panel.add(brandLabel);
        panel.add(brandField);
        panel.add(typeLabel);
        panel.add(typeField);
        panel.add(deliveryLabel);
        panel.add(deliveryField);
        panel.add(packageLabel);
        panel.add(packageField);
        panel.add(nameLabel);
        panel.add(nameField);
        panel.add(generateButton);
        panel.add(codeLabel);
        add(panel);

        // Set the GUI properties
        setTitle("DITCO PRODUCT CODE");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            // Read the inputs from the user
            String brand = brandField.getText();
            String type = typeField.getText();
            String delivery = deliveryField.getText();
            String packageName = packageField.getText();
            String name = nameField.getText();

            // Read the Excel file
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("DITCO PRODUCT CODE.xlsx"));
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            // Get the indices of the rows and columns
            int brandIndex = getIndex(sheet, "Marka", brand);
            int typeIndex = getIndex(sheet, "Tip", type);
            int deliveryIndex = getIndex(sheet, "Gönderim Tipi", delivery);
            int groupIndex = getIndex(sheet, "1-40 Bottle", packageName);
            int productIndex = Integer.parseInt(name.substring(1));

            // Calculate the code
            int brandCode = (int) sheet.getRow(brandIndex).getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
            int typeCode = (int) sheet.getRow(typeIndex).getCell(1).getNumericCellValue();
            int deliveryCode = (int) sheet.getRow(deliveryIndex).getCell(2).getNumericCellValue();
            int productCode = (int) sheet.getRow(groupIndex * 10 + productIndex - 1).getCell(7).getNumericCellValue();
            int code = brandCode * 100000 + typeCode * 10000 + deliveryCode * 1000 + productCode;

            // Display the code in the GUI
            codeLabel.setText("Code: " + code);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private int getIndex(Sheet sheet, String columnName, String value) {
        int index = -1;
        Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
            if (row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().equals(columnName)) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            row = sheet.getRow(i);
            Cell cell = row.getCell(index);
            if (cell != null && cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING && cell.getStringCellValue().equals(value)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ProductCodeGenerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: If it were me, I think I would read the Excel file and translate it into a set of `Dictionary`s that map each name to a number.  Now, you can do a simple lookup to do the mapping.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But I have this all in a one excel file, for example Keys for the brands start from B5 to B24 and the values of it from C5 to C24. How can i implement this?

Comment: You have already shown how to extract one cell at a time.  Just extract the rows in each column to a different lookup dictionary.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach and intermediate data structure(s); include a _small_ amount of sample data.